# Confused over behavior of List.mapi in F#

Tags: collections, f#, functional-programming

I am building some equations in F#, and when working on my polynomial class I found some odd behavior using List.mapi

Basically, each polynomial has an array, so `3*x^2 + 5*x + 6` would be `[|6, 5, 3|]` in the array, so, when adding polynomials, if one array is longer than the other, then I just need to append the extra elements to the result, and that is where I ran into a problem.

Later I want to generalize it to not always use a `float`, but that will be after I get more working.

So, the problem is that I expected `List.mapi` to return a `List` not individual elements, but, in order to put the lists together I had to put `[]` around my use of `mapi`, and I am curious why that is the case.

This is more complicated than I expected, I thought I should be able to just tell it to make a new `List` starting at a certain index, but I can't find any function for that.

```
type Polynomial() =
    let mutable coefficients:float [] = Array.empty
    member self.Coefficients with get() = coefficients
    static member (+) (v1:Polynomial, v2:Polynomial) =
        let ret = List.map2(fun c p -> c + p) (List.ofArray v1.Coefficients) (List.ofArray v2.Coefficients)
        let a = List.mapi(fun i x -> x)
        match v1.Coefficients.Length - v2.Coefficients.Length with
            | x when x < 0 ->
                ret :: [((List.ofArray v1.Coefficients) |> a)]
            | x when x > 0 ->
                ret :: [((List.ofArray v2.Coefficients) |> a)]
            | _ -> [ret]
```

Comment: As a side note - you don't need that `with get()` there, as it will be implied if you write simply `member self.Coefficients = coefficients`. It's only needed when you also need a `set`.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev - Thank you. I haven't decided if I will need a set() or not, so I just put in there in case. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that a straightforward implementation using lists and recursion would be simpler in this case. An alternative implementation of the `Polynomial` class might look roughly like this:

```
// The type is immutable and takes initial list as constructor argument
type Polynomial(coeffs:float list) = 
  // Local recursive function implementing the addition using lists
  let rec add l1 l2 = 
    match l1, l2 with
    | x::xs, y::ys -> (x+y) :: (add xs ys)
    | rest, [] | [], rest -> rest

  member self.Coefficients = coeffs

  static member (+) (v1:Polynomial, v2:Polynomial) = 
    // Add lists using local function
    let newList = add v1.Coefficients v2.Coefficients
    // Wrap result into new polynomial
    Polynomial(newList)
```

It is worth noting that you don't really need mutable field in the class, since the `+` operator creates and returns a new instance of the type, so the type is fully immutable (as you'd usually want in F#).

The nice thing in the `add` function is that after processing all elements that are available in *both lists*, you can simply return the tail of the non-empty list as the rest.

---

If you wanted to implement the same functionality using arrays, then it may be better to use a simple `for` loop (since arrays are, in principle, imperative, the usual imperative patterns are usually the best option for dealing with them). However, I don't think there is any particular reason for preferring arrays (maybe performance, but that would have to be evaluated later during the development).

As Pavel points out, `::` operator appends a single element to the front of a list (see the `add` function above, which demonstrates that). You could write what you wanted using `@` which concatenates lists, or using `Array.concat` (which concatenates a sequence of arrays).

An implementation using higher-order functions and arrays is also possible - the best version I can come up with would look like this:

```
let add (a1:_[]) (a2:_[]) =
  // Add parts where both arrays have elements
  let l = min a1.Length a2.Length
  let both = Array.map2 (+) a1.[0 .. l-1] a2.[0 .. l-1]  
  // Take the rest of the longer array
  let rest = 
    if a1.Length > a2.Length 
    then a1.[l .. a1.Length - 1] 
    else a2.[l .. a2.Length - 1]
  // Concatenate them
  Array.concat [ both; rest ]

add [| 6; 5; 3 |] [| 7 |]
```

This uses *slices* (e.g. `a.[0 .. l]`) which give you a part of an array - you can use these to take the parts where both arrays have elements and the remaining part of the longer array.

Comment: Thank you. I have many functions in Java I am trying to move over to F# and it is not a trivial process, but, I had one correction to make, the add function was missing as the (+) operator is static. I just put it into the (+) operator.

Comment: Nice update. I think you can use `Array.append` instead of `Array.concat` to be a bit more concise and fast (it specifically takes 2 array arguments, rather than a `seq` of arrays).

Comment: Also, for array slices, if you don't specify the upper bound, the slice is to the end of the array. This lets you write it a bit shorter: `(if a1.Length > a2.Length then a1 else a2)[l ..]`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding what operator `::` does. It's not used to concatenate two lists. It's used to prepend a *single element* to the list. Consequently, it's type is:

```
'a -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

In your case, you're giving `ret` as a first argument, and `ret` is itself a `float list`. Consequently, it expects the second argument to be of type `float list list` - hence why you need to add an extra `[]` to the second argument to make it to compile - and that will also be the result type of your operator `+`, which is probably not what you want.

You can use `List.concat` to concatenate two (or more) lists, but that is inefficient. In your example, I don't see the point of using lists at all - all this converting back & forth is going to be costly. For arrays, you can use `Array.append`, which is better.

By the way, it's not clear what is the purpose of `mapi` in your code at all. It's exactly the same as `map`, except for the index argument, but you're not using it, and your mapping is the identity function, so it's effectively a no-op. What's it about?

Comment: I am not using the index yet, but the purpose of mapi is to skip anything that was already added together, so I would only include those elements in any index higher than the smaller of the two.

Comment: If you want to skip the first _n_ items, look at `Seq.skip`.